# Selenium | Unable to locate element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to click a button but none of the selectors work. Any ideas?

My code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Συνέχεια']").click()
```

[The Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBnO4.png)

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root jss261 MuiButton-contained jss594 MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-containedSizeLarge MuiButton-sizeLarge" tabindex="0" type="button" data-testid="button" label="Συνέχεια"><span class="MuiButton-label"><div class="jss603">Συνέχεια</div></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
```

Comment: I'd worry more about the captcha than the button!

Comment: I am able to bybass the reCaptcha